# Make line breaks in PowerShell output appear as such in HTML

Tags: html, powershell, escaping, output, line-breaks

Running `Invoke-command {net localgroup administrators} -comp computername` and getting the results in an HTML.

How do I get this output with breaks so it looks like the direct execution result, which is something like this:

```
Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domain1\Group1 
Administrator 
Domain2\Ggroup1  
Domain2\Group2  
The command completed successfully.
```

When I put the text above in an HTML document, I get something like this:

```
Alias name administrators Comment Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain Members ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Domain\Group1 Administrator Domain2\Group1 Domain2\Group2 The command completed successfully.
```

Even with `-replace` and `` `n `` etc I am only able to break the first and last text lines, but the result (actual domain\group names, come as a single line).

Comment: How are you making the HTML?

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight: PowerShell is incidental to this question; this is solely about how to preserve line breaks in plain text when putting it into an HTML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're getting from Invoke-Command is a string array. The easiest thing you can do is to join the output with `<br />` tag.

```
$output = Invoke-command {net localgroup administrators} -ComputerName ...
$output -join "<br />"
```

Comment: That'll work (and kudos for figuring out the core issue), though wrapping the entire output in a `<pre>` element is probably preferably (ironically, that very technique is used in the question's source code):   `"<pre>$($output -join "\`n")</pre>"`

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 will up vote once I can. I did edit the question using the <br> to show it the way I need in the report. Appreciate the feedback.